# How to count Instances of certain class in COCO format dataset in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, data-annotations

I have done some data annotation work by using labelme software. So, I have now the complete dataset in COCO format.

However, I am struggling with a few things.

In my dataset, I have in total of 10 images, and 3 categories,i.e., apple, mango, and banana.

Of those 10 images, 6 images contain apple, 5 images contain mango, and 4 contain banana.

With my code, I can count this thing.

***Among those 6 images which contain apples, 4 images have 5 apples
each. So now I want to know the total number of instances of each
category in my dataset. Is it possible?***

for example, I am attaching one image.

[image]

On this image, there is X number of instances from Class Elephant. I want to count the X from my annotated dataset. I need help because I am very new to this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm probably far too late to help you, but for anyone else.

COCO annotation files have 5 keys (for object detection) “info”, “licenses”, “images”, “annotations”, “categories”.

Annotations has a dict for each element of a list.
Categories has a mapping between category IDs and their names.

First you have to get that ID -> Class Mapping.

Then iterate through those annotations adding a count to the relevant class (increment counter in dictionary by 1).

```
def get_count_per_class(data: dict) -> dict:
    """
    Count per class given COCO annotations in dict format.
    """
    id_to_class_name = {x['id']: x['name'] for x in data['categories']} 
    annotations = data['annotations']
    
    counts = {}
    for annotation in annotations:
        class_name = id_to_class_name[annotation['category_id']]
        counts[class_name] = counts.get(class_name, 0) + 1
        
    return counts
```